# Combining Three.js and Easel.js

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, easeljs

I would like to know how I can combine both Three.js and Easel.js?
I know that there are few games are using these 2 libraries.
But can someone describe/explain how normally these 2 libraries are used together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the current state of play is with three.js, but I've semi-successfully combined them using 3 overlayed divs in the past: bottom canvas, webgl/three.js, top canvas. Then just draw and update all 3 canvases appropriately. A bit messy but it sort-of works!